# Doxygen anchor inside function

Tags: anchor, doxygen, ref

I have a filter which converts actual code into @code/@endcode blocks but I can't figure out a way to create a @ref link to these sections.

Here's a snippet of what I mean:

```
/**
 * Refer to this example: @ref example1
 * @param $arg1
 * @param $arg2
 */
public function somefunction($arg1, $arg2)
{
    /**
     * @anchor example1 @code
    if (true)
    {
        $this = 'bollox';
    }
     * @endcode
     **/
}
```

The output of this looks pretty much like what I want (although I haven't decided on how best to truly indicate the link point...**exmple1** springs to mind).

The problem is that the hyperlink for **example1** links to the *filename*.html#example1.

I've checked the source and there is an anchor class being generated.

I understand I'm not really using anchor as documented.

Any suggestions welcome.

Note: I'm not specifically trying to get *anchor* to work...just want a hyperlink/bookmark to link a \ref (or similar).

Comment: Form the documentation: Note
Anchors can currently only be put into a comment block that is marked as a page (using \page) or mainpage
(\mainpage).

Comment: Right...the problem with prefixing with a page directive is that it puts it on its own page as opposed to below the function in the resulting html.

Comment: I just answered a question about adding anchors to the code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35434488/2214806

Comment: You might want to try using the \snippet command (don't forget to add your source to the EXAMPLE_PATH in the config)

Comment: The html href solution doesn't really work for me in my scenario above as I need to know the source page (which isn't obvious but can be derived with some effort...but there's the danger it will change).

I think perhaps the snippet command is the closest fit...it's just a bit more work than I wanted to put in...but as I have a filter I may be able to massage a fake @ command into a snippet.