# Create doxygen link from text

Tags: doxygen

I use doxygen to track features and user stories in my project. To do that, I would like to create links by the following way:
There are enumerated paragraphs, which are the featerues:

```
-# <b>FT001:</b> I, as
-# <b>FT002:</b> I, as
```

and so on... You see the feature IDs. When I write user stories, I would like to refer to the feature like:

```
//! <b>Affected features:</b> some_clickable_link_to_FT001 <br>
```

Can anybody help me how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with plain old HTML. Put a DIV around where the link should take you:

```
-# <DIV ID="FT001"><b>FT001:</b></DIV> I, as
-# <DIV ID="FT002"><b>FT002:</b></DIV> I, as
```

I'm not an HTML expert, but `<A NAME="anchor" ...` might be better than `<DIV ...`.

---

Elsewhere in the same file you can reference it with this.

```
<a href="#FT001">Link to section elsewhere in this file</a>
```

---

You might want to create an alias in your config file to make this more readable, like either of these:

```
ALIASES +=   "anchor{2}=<DIV ID=\"\1\"> \2 <DIV>
ALIASES += "bookmark{2}=<DIV ID=\"\1\"> \2 <DIV>
```

---

You can also reference the link like this.

```
[Link to elsewhere](#FT001)
```